# Diagonal lines in a qt grid layout cell

Tags: c++, qt, c++14

I am working on making a kakuro game. I want to make diagonal lines for the sum cells in a kakuro game. I have a grid layout set up but don't know how I would make a diagonal line and put two numbers in that cell, one on top if the line and one on the bottom section. Visit [kakuros.com](http://kakuros.com) to understand what I am trying to explain. I really appreciate any help

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be sure to read how to [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11044239/1329652) might provide some pointers.